# Type Parameter Class with generic java

Tags: java, micronaut

I am trying to use the generic class in java 15 with the below code

```
@Singleton
public class GenericRepository<T> implements IGenericRepository<T>{
    private final MongoClient mongoClient;
    
    public GenericRepository(MongoClient mongoClient) {
        this.mongoClient = mongoClient;
    }

    public MongoCollection<T> getCollection(String collectionName) {
        return mongoClient
                .getDatabase("main")
                .getCollection(collectionName, T.class);
    }
}
```

I can't use T.class, how can I solve this

Solution I found

```
@Singleton
public class GenericRepository<T> implements IGenericRepository<T>{
    private final MongoClient mongoClient;
    private final Class<T> typeParameterClass;

    public GenericRepository(MongoClient mongoClient, Class<T> typeParameterClass) {
        this.mongoClient = mongoClient;
        this.typeParameterClass = typeParameterClass;
    }

    public MongoCollection<T> getCollection(String collectionName) {
        return mongoClient
                .getDatabase("main")
                .getCollection(collectionName, this.typeParameterClass);
    }
}
```

Since using this solution is quite extra code, is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: Generics are erased at run-time in Java, which is why you can't use `T.class`. The solution you found is typically the one used (but note even that solution is not fully type safe as e.g. a `List<U>` can not be fully represented by a `Class` object).

Comment: Not in vanilla Java. Are you using Spring by any chance?

Comment: I am using Micronaut framework, sorry not using spring

Comment: Note it seems odd to me for a generic type to be used as a singleton. The fact it's generic suggests different parameterizations, but making it a singleton suggests only one parameterization (in which case, why make the type generic?).

Comment: With @Slaw's comment aside regarding the use of generics in singletons, the solution that you have found seems to be the right way to do this. Instead of passing this to constructor, it should be passed to the method  that is typecasting. Between, its better to look at a way to configure `mongoClient` to use `main` as database and make a call to its `getCollection`. This should eliminate the complete class altogether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A singleton class, whose only constructor takes parameters, *and* is parameterized?

Your code makes no sense. The problem you're running into is significant in other contexts, but not this one. There is no direct solution to this problem (the problem being: Generics are erased), but there are different code styles that avoid it.

The problem is, because the problem doesn't even apply to this situation, it's hard to explain how one would rewrite this code so the problem goes away as a general principle.

Here, you'd just... remove the type param, get rid of that interface (in general if you have `IFoo` hanging around, something's not right), simple as that.

If you want to generalize this concept, so that you can make a lot of these (Let's say you have one of these classes to retrieve the Foos, and another to retrieve the Bars), you CAN fetch the `<X>` in specifically `public class FooFetcher implements GenericFetcher<X>`, though it's a bit tricky (you'd use `getGenericSuper` from your own `java.lang.Class` and take it from there. There's a ton of caveats in this situation, so I won't expand any further on this, just know that's how you could do it.

If, in a different situation, you do need to convey generics in a runtime-queryable way, the problem with your style is that `a class object` and `a generics param` overlap but aren't the same. `int` has a class object (`int.class`), but `List<int>` is not valid java code. `List<String>` is valid generics (`List<List<String>> x;` is valid java), but `List<String>.class` isn't a thing and never will be, only `List.class` can be. Same goes for `?`, `? extends Map<?, List<? extends Number>> & Serializable`, which is valid generics, but rather obviously not at all something you can represent with a `java.lang.Class` type. Therefore, if you do want generics as a runtime queryable concept, search the web for 'super type tokens' - but note that they require MORE code than what you have here, not less. They're just actually capable of representing exactly what generics can represent.

As a general rule of thumb if you're relying on the generics of java.lang.Class to glue your code together you've done something wrong, and you probably want factories.